# ios: reading Chinese characters of a html source code

Tags: ios, encoding

I'm trying to read and save Chinese characters written in websites !
For example: 
html source code has this line:

`title="网络歌手`"

when I read this as NSString, the value returned is in the format like:

`\UT0212\UT0999`

something like that.
I have tried converting using gb2312 and utf-8, etc. encoders, but I don't quite get the exact Chinese. Sometimes I get close to Chinese, but not the exact words.

Any help is appreciated !

Regards,
Suraj

Answer (score 0):

http://www.pinyin.info/tools/converter/chars2uninumbers.html

I believe you would have to convert the characters to unicode...similar to what they did in the above article